# php artisan serve error: could not find the input file(Running in the project folder Laravel v6)

Tags: php, laravel

I am in the project directory but when I run `php artisan serve` I get this error that `Could not open input file: artisan`. It was initially working but then when I walk up this morning and did the command to begin working on the project I encountered the error! Please, someone, help me know where the problem might be. All the other answers I have found on StackOverflow are the talking about not running it in the project directory but for me, I am in the project directory!

[image]

Comment: did u tried `composer update`? looks like there's not a problem with your laravel project.

Comment: first try `composer dump-autoload`, then you can also compare your artisan file with the one on github https://github.com/abbbhucho/laravel/blob/master/artisan

Comment: try running `php artisan` only, it should return display available command

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any problem with your project directory.

this might be an access problem. You can try this in project directory:

`chmod +x artisan`.

Try with this :

`php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` then use `localhost:8000`  in browser.

Comment: I did this but now when I do `php artisan serve` it takes a lot of time but doesn't do anything

Comment: do you get list of commends with `php artisan` ?

Comment: I tried `php artisan -S localhost:8000` it starts the server but when I visit localhost:8000, I find page not found. Though let me try what you have there adding -t public/

Comment: `PHP 7.3.12 Development Server started at Sun Aug 16 12:37:48 2020
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\freelance\rivala0\public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.` When I try visit the localhost, it tells me that the server can't be reached.

Comment: do you have xampp or anything like this in your pc which is activated apache server on localhost?

Comment: I had installed bitnami WAMP which was using port 8000 but then I uninstalled it. I restarted the PC but that didn't help.

Comment: so use `php artisan serve` if problem didn't solved. i wanna make sure where's the problem, did u tried another laravel project to make sure problem is with your project or it's global?
also did you try `php artisan config:cache`,  `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan view:cache` or `php artisan route:cache` to see if it work?

Comment: if above solutions didn't worked Talk to me [Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219898/php-artisan-serve-error-could-not-find-the-input-filerunning-in-the-project-fol)

Comment: I uninstalled xampp and reinstalled it again and now when I run `php artisan serve` I get this error in all the projects ` include(C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\freelance\idevs\vendor\composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieS
  erviceProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` . When I do `composer install, composer update, composer dump-autoload ` It tells me that everything is up to date.

Comment: Talk to me Here